# Excel 2010 if lookup in multiple lines

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to do the following:

```
one sheet |   in another sheet
-----------------------------------
 C        |    R     S
448       |   497   517
          |   526   542
453       |   812   814
```

can I check if C is between any value in all lines for R and S and then perform an operation if is it true?

an example for if `=if(C(1)<=R(:)&&C(1)>=S(:))`

Comment: Please expand or clarify your question. You want to know if a value in `c` is between any two values in a `row` of RS or a `column` of R *or* S?

Comment: What if the value in C is between more than one set?

Comment: In what cell do you want the formula?

Answer (score 0):

This is clunky and awkward, but it works, just change the ranges and the `do stuff`

Someone might come along and make it better so that it stops checking after the final condition is met.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sks()
    Dim Rng, Rng2, Rng3, c1, c2, c3 As Range

    Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    Set Rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
    Set Rng3 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("B:B")

    For Each c1 In Rng

        If c1.Value <> "" Then

            For Each c2 In Rng2

                If c2.Value <> "" Then

                   If c1.Value >= c2.Value Then

                      If c1.Value <= c2.Offset(0, 1).Value Then

                          'do stuff c1.Offset(0, 1).Value = "yes"

                       Else: End If
                    Else: End If
                Else: End If

             Next c2

          Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```